# Can I create Windows Phone 8.0 class library project and use that in Windows phone 8.1 project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

In my windows phone 8.1 project I am using MediaCapture Api for capturing photo's, but I experienced issue on the devices that comes with 8.0 and later upgarded to 8.1,
The problem is that on such devices camera capture fails after taking 10-15 images and it's just saves green screen instead of original image. 
So what I thought is to create 8.0 class library and use CameraCaptureTask of 8.0.
Will that work? If so than Is it recommended way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing that your 8.1 project is 8.1 XAML not 8.1 Silverlight the answer is no. The camera API really sucks in 8.1 XAML, if it is a core functionality of your app, just go with 8.1 Silverlight.